# Changing linux network connection type

Tags: linux, powershell, winrm

I've tried `Set-WSManQuickConfig` command in Powershell, but it could not configure the firewall:

```
Set-WSManQuickConfig : WinRM firewall exception will not work since one of the network connection types on this machine is set to Public. Change the network connection type to either Domain or Private and try again.
```

The problem is with a remote (virtual machine) linux OS. How can I change the network connection type in linux? I suppose it's Public as default. Is it that obvious as in Windows: changing the connection type to Work? But in Linux, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux does not have any concept of 'network type' as you know it from Windows.

I'm assuming the network type is basically a sort of firewall pre-configuration. You can configure the firewall using iptables.

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) is one of the many introductions to iptables. The most important thing to remember is that, unlike typical Windows firewalls, iptables doesn't filter applications but ports.

Answer (score 0):

First -> be careful to chhange to domain or private :

[image: Seven Network configuration]

Second -> on Seven or W2K8, be careful o use the real administrator user and not the pseudo one created at installation.